# BASH - Check if a number exists in one CSV and display warning if in new CSV

Tags: bash, csv, sed, awk, sh

So I have one csv file which contains something like the following:

```
number,name,phone
11111,Dr Spoon, 0115 1234 567
11112,Mrs Eggface, 07711111111
```

and another csv with a long list of numbers:

```
number
11145
15687
11598
11112
```

Now I need to somehow check that a row in the first csv doesn't exist in the second, and if it does to show me that it does. Any suggestions? Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will print any lines in `file1` where the first field is found in `file2`:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR>1&&NR==FNR{a[$1];next}FNR>1&&($1 in a)' file2 file1
11112,Mrs Eggface, 07711111111
```

Add a block to format the printing however you like:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR>1&&NR==FNR{a[$1];next}FNR>1&&($1 in a){print $1,"in both!"}' f2 f1
11112 in both!
```

Comment: Brilliant! Worked perfectly! Thanks :)